# PhpMyAdmin keeps refreshing automatically on Chrome in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, phpmyadmin

When I log in to it (running on localhost) it keeps refreshing like crazy. It works alright in firefox though.

Anyone had this problem before?

Comment: I have this problem right now.

Comment: Sorry but I never solved this problem. Ended up using firefox for a while, and then came back to chrome and it was just fine. As far as I remember, the only thing I done to chrome was to uninstall all the plug-ins (due to unrelated issue). But I am not even sure if that was what solved it.. Maybe post this question again?

Comment: Looks like my issue was due to a Chrome addon.

Comment: Did you manage to narrow down to a particular add on?

Comment: Something called LivePage which I use for web development to see changes in code show up automatically in the browser.

Comment: @galdikas I'm quite sure you solved it by switching to Firefox...because it worked for me as well! Thanks a lot!